# error connecting to sql server compact file in VS2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, connection-string

I use following connection string for connecting to my SQL Server Compact database (`.SDF` file) in a VS 2012 (.NET 4) Win form app:

```
SqlConnection SQLConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=d:\\mydb.sdf;");
```

but I get following error, what is going wrong?

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SqlCeConnection` instead of `SqlConnection`.

Comment: thanks, it worked, now I want to create a table:            SqlCeCommand myCommand = new SqlCeCommand("CREATE TABLE tblUser (ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,PersonelCode varchar(10),FirstName nvarchar(50),LastName nvarchar(50),FatherName nvarchar(50),BirthPlace nvarchar(30),IDCard nvarchar(20),..... but it says varchar type is not supported!!! what can I use instead?

Comment: Use `nvarchar`, as SQL Server Compact Edition does not support varchar. Here, catch a list of supported data types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424.aspx. The difference between varchar and nvarchar (at least for full SQL Server) is that varchar has 8-bit codepages, while nvarchar uses multichar unicode by default.